# How to change decimal value string into int without loosing decimal values?

Tags: java

I am working on a pretty old Java application and I can not change Integer field to something else which can hold decimal values, so I need to convert some decimal string like "100.00", "3.33" "33.44" to Integer without loosing fractional values.

```java
@Test
public void NumberFormatTest(){
    String stringValue = "100.00";

    int testTest = ?  //what I can do here to get exact 100.00 in testTest variable ? 

    log.info("outPutValue {} ", testTest);
}
```

Currently its using `Integer.parseInt(stringValue)` and this is throwing

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100.00"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
```

Comment: An `int` doesn't store decimal values, so you can't do this.

Comment: Code snippets are only intended for JavaScript/HTML/CSS questions, please don't use them for other languages.

Comment: You could store the "cents" value (e.g 100.00 is 10000, 3.33 is 333, 33.44 is 3344), but I guess retrofitting your application to do that is likely to introduce more bugs than fixing it correctly.

Comment: Before posting here, study *The Java Tutorials* provided free-of-cost by Oracle Corp. See [*Primitive Data Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

> I am working on pretty old java code application and I can not change Integer field to something else which can hold decimal values

That is because `int` can only hold whole numbers. For decimal values you need to use `float` or `double`:

```
String s = "3.33";
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Alternatively, you might want to look into `BigDecimal`. Depending on your exact needs, this might be a better fit.

p.s. `int`, `float` and `double` are primitive types. `Integer`, `Float` and `Double` are class wrapper for those types. These are two different things. I recommend you read more about these differences to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Another one is `BigDecimal` (which might be a better choice than `float` or `double`, depending on the actual needs of the OP).

Comment: You could just explain the difference between `int` and `Integer`: `int` is a primitive type, which directly holds a number, while `Integer` is a class, which makes an `Integer`-type variable hold a reference to an instance of `Integer`, which can also be `null`.

Comment: @Cactusroot Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my answer to be a little less harsh.